# Using matrix inversion and summation together. How to compute $(A+B^{-1})^{-1}|x\rangle$

Tags: hhl-algorithm

I need to compute $(A+B^{-1})^{-1}|x\rangle$, where A and B is hermitian for simplicity.

I read out about matrix inversion algorithms (HHL, QSVE,...), and algorithms of summing up of matrices(LCU, Lie–Trotter product formula,...) but I don't understand how to glue this two parts together.

Comment: If you would like to get a useful answer, then I think you should include more details about your question.